# How to exclude Views results for custom entities for which a user has no permission to view them?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom entity which I list in views. I set access control for them, but when I list in views these entities, all entities shows up, those one too, which  the user does not have permission to access.

What do I need to implement to filter out those entities, which the user does not have right to view?

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the [list of Views hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/8.4.x), I think [hook_views_pre_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/8.4.x) is the one you can use to filter results before they are rendered.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function MODULE_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if (!empty($view->result)) {
    $entities = [
      'your_custom_entity_id',
      'another_entity_id',
    ];

    foreach ($view->result as $key => $result) {
      if (empty($result->_entity)) {
        continue;
      }

      if (!in_array($result->_entity->getEntityTypeId(), $entities)) {
        continue;
      }

      $access = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getAccessControlHandler($result->_entity->getEntityTypeId())
        ->access($result->_entity, 'view', NULL, TRUE);

      if (!$access->isAllowed()) {
        unset($view->result[$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't know this will work or not, I've already has a solution. But I think you can have some issue here if you have a pager.

Answer (score 1):

Actually my final solution was this: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2997705 which maybe not the best, but it works.